# FlashAirのLuaで日本語ファイル名に変更するには？

Tags: flashair, lua

FlashAirのLuaで日本語ファイル名に変更しようと試みているのですが、変更できません。
コードは以下の通りです。

```
fa.rename("/sample.jpg", "/サンプル.jpg")
```

LuaファイルがUTF-8の時はファイル名変更ができず、Shift-JISでは文字化けします。
正しく日本語ファイル名に変更するにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか？
ご存知でしたらご教授のほどお願いいたします。

合掌。